# Adding fade effect to Primefaces p:spotlight

Tags: jquery, primefaces

How to add show and hide effect to [PrimeFaces Spotlight](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/spotlight.xhtml)?

In `<p:dialog>` I can add it directly through `showEffect` in its property. But `<p:spotlight>` seems like doesn't have this property. I have also try to create the widget manually by using `PrimeFaces.cw` as below:

```
PrimeFaces.cw("Spotlight","spotlight",
{
    id:"j_idt54",
    target:"rowPayment",
    showEffect:"fade",
    hideEffect:"fade"
});
```

As expected, it doesn't work.

I have also try to show and hide it using jQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` function like `$('#id').fadeIn();` also not working, but it works if I apply to dialog, it will fade in and fade out, just not working on spotlight.

Maybe the structure of dialog and spotlight is different that's why it only works on dialog but not spotlight? The jQuery scripts that I have tried are all fine, no error at all, but it just not working.

Comment: The source is open. Check in github. Overriding (extending) the javascript functions is not that hard.

Comment: Hi, if you could provide a little help, like giving a kick off example on how to override (and which to override), that would be great.